# jquery each() and js array not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code in html:

```
<div class="box-content">
    <span>
        <h4 id="title">title1</h4>
        <h5 id="texto"></h5>
    </span>
    <span>
        <h4 id="title">title2</h4>
        <h5 id="texto"></h5>
    </span>
    <span>
        <h4 id="title">title3</h4>
        <h5 id="texto"></h5>
    </span>
    ....
</div>
```

and I need to populate that structure using an array as follows

```
$(".pluscontrol").click(function(){
    var itemBoxValues1 = ["text1", "text2", "text3"];
    var i = 0;
    $('.box-content').children().each(function(){
        var tmp = itemBoxValues1[i];
        $('.box-content').children().children("h5").text(" id: "+i+" val "+tmp);
        i++;
    });
});
```

but it doesn't work as I expected because in all `<h5>` elements print this:

```
<span>
    <h4 id="title">title n </h4>
    <h5 id="texto">id: 35 val 23</h5>
</span>
```

I don't understand why it's happen. Thanks.

Comment: You're using the children selector inside of your each. Your `this` inside the each function will be the current object you're iterating. Reduce `$('.box-content').children().children("h5")...` to `$(this).children('h5')...`

Comment: An `id` by definition should be unique.

Comment: Unrelated but I'm curious, why increment the value `i` yourself? You could do `.each(function(index, element){})`

Comment: cannot use same `id` for all elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".pluscontrol").click(function(){
    var itemBoxValues1 = ["text1", "text2", "text3"];
    var i = 0;
    $('.box-content').children().each(function(){
        var tmp = itemBoxValues1[i];
        $(this).children("h5").text(" id: "+ i +" val "+ tmp);
        i++;
    });
});
```

**Update**

Inside each, you need to find children of current `span`, so you need to use `$(this)`, this `$('.box-content').children().children("h5")` will return all `h5` tags

Also you can use following to save some lines of your code:

```
var itemBoxValues1 = ["text1", "text2", "text3"];

$('.box-content > span').each(function(i, span){    
    $(span).children("h5").text(" id: "+ i +" val "+ itemBoxValues1[i]);    
});
```

Comment: yes, the problem was solved, but I dont't understand why.

Answer (score 1):

Make your selector tighter so you don't need `.children()` methods. With `.each()` you don't need to increment `i` because it's built in and the `this` is also established as well.

Also, you need to use class instead of id, because id must be unique per document (i.e. the webpage). With classes (which you'll need to change to or HTML is not valid), you could use `$('.texto')` instead of `$(.box-content h5')`.

```js
$(".pluscontrol").click(function() {
  var tmp = ["text1", "text2", "text3"];
  $('.box-content h5').each(function(i) {
    $(this).text(" id: " + i + " val: " + tmp[i]);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box-content">
  <span>
        <h4 class="title">title1</h4>
        <h5 class="texto"></h5>
    </span>
  <span>
        <h4 class="title">title2</h4>
        <h5 class="texto"></h5>
    </span>
  <span>
        <h4 class="title">title3</h4>
        <h5 class="texto"></h5>
    </span>

  <button class='pluscontrol'>GO</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting

```
id: 35 val 23
```

in each iteration because the reference to each of the span elements is getting overwritten every time the loop runs (more explanation below).

I would write it like this:

```
    $(".pluscontrol").click(function(){
        var itemBoxValues1 = ["text1", "text2", "text3"];

        $('.box-content').children().each(function(i){
            var tmp = itemBoxValues1[i];
            $(this).children("h5").text(" id: " + i + " val: " + tmp);
        });
    });
```

1. You don't need variable "i", nor do you need to increment it inside the loop.  jQuery.each() gives you an index variable and automatically increments it inside the loop.
2. You don't need to re-query the DOM for the children of your span elements.  Just call $(this) to get the spans, 'this' is a reference to each object being iterated inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<title></title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">


[class^="B_class"]:first-child{
   display: none;
}

</style>
<body>


<div class="box-content">
    <span>
        <h4 id="title">title1</h4>
        <h5 id="text0"></h5>
    </span>
    <span>
        <h4 id="title">title2</h4>
        <h5 id="text1"></h5>
    </span>
    <span>
        <h4 id="title">title3</h4>
        <h5 id="text2"></h5>
    </span>
    <input type="button" value="plus+" id="plus">
</div>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
   var items = $(".box-content span").length;
   var itemBoxValues1 = ["text1", "text2", "text3"];


   $("#plus").click(function(){
      for(var i=0;i<items;i++)
         {
            var tmp = itemBoxValues1[i];
            var theid = "#text"+i;
            $(theid).text("id :"+i+" val "+tmp);
         }
   });

});

</script>

</html>
```

**note : don't use same id name for elements.**

Answer (score 0):

An `id` by definition is unique. You can use `data-` attributes or a class instead.

Here's how you may re-write your code to take advantage of all the available data:

```js
$('.box-content > span').each(function(i,v) {
    $(v).find('h5').text(' id: ' + (i+1) + '; val: ' + $(v).find('h4').text() );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box-content">
    <span>
        <h4 data-id="title">title1</h4>
        <h5 data-id="texto"></h5>
    </span>
    <span>
        <h4 data-id="title">title2</h4>
        <h5 data-id="texto"></h5>
    </span>
    <span>
        <h4 data-id="title">title3</h4>
        <h5 data-id="texto"></h5>
    </span>
    ....
</div>
```